# admob rewords ads not showing kotlin

Tags: kotlin, admob, ads

banner ads and Interstitial ads are work fine but rewords ads not showing I thing the problem in my code
here is my code
after update I don't have error but ads not showing

```
      @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        class ResultActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        
            private var mRewardedAd: RewardedAd? = null
            override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_result)
                // TODO (STEP 6: Hide the status bar and get the details from intent and set it to the UI. And also add a click event to the finish button.)
                // START
                // Hide the status bar.
                window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    
    
                 val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        
                RewardedAd.load(
                    this,
                    "ca-app-pub-5757320647",
       

     adRequest,
            object : RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                    mRewardedAd = null
                }

                override fun onAdLoaded(rewardedAd: RewardedAd) {

                    mRewardedAd = rewardedAd
                    mRewardedAd?.fullScreenContentCallback =
                        object : FullScreenContentCallback() {}
        }

    }

)


val userName = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.USER_NAME)
tv_name.text = userName

            val totalQuestions = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.TOTAL_QUESTIONS, 0)
            val correctAnswers = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.CORRECT_ANSWERS, 0)
    
            tv_score.text = "Your Score is $correctAnswers out of $totalQuestions."
    
            btn_finish.setOnClickListener {
    
                mRewardedAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {}
                startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
    
    
    
            }
        }
    }
```

**is there any wrong in my code **

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFaQy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRR9P.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are starting an activity just after calling a request to load a rewarded ad which will show the activity instead of the ad since ads cannot be played in background. Instead take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded#set_the_fullscreencontentcallback) and call `startActivity` inside `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent` .

Edit:- Try this

```
mRewardedAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
  override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
  }
  
  override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError) {
    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
  }

  override fun onAdImpression() {
    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
  }

  override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
  }
}
```

Comment: mRewardedAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback(){}
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)) //like this?

Comment: No. like this `mRewardedAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback(){ startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)) }`

Comment: the image in the post

Comment: use this@ResultActivity.startActivity

Comment: still the same problem check the post again i updated

Comment: do not call the startActivity as it is implement methods of fullScreenContentCallback first

Comment: can you edit your answer and add the full code please

Comment: check it again i mean my code in the post i don't have error but no ads

Comment: check the picture in the post

Comment: Use this@ResultActivity in place of this while creating intent